# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: hour must be in 0..23

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, eve

I'm working on an Eve tutorial and I'm stuck at an early point. I just have two python files:

app.py:

```
    from eve import Eve
    app = Eve()
```

settings.py:

```
    DOMAIN = {
        'people': {}
    }
```

I also have mongodb running which eve needs to run. When I run the eve app and then attempt to consume it with the regular localhost:5000, it works just fine. But when I attempt to consume localhost:5000/people, it results in a timeout with this error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: hour must be in 0..23

I'm working on ubuntu 17.10 os, eve 0.8, pymongo 3.7.1, and mongodb 4.0.1. I just can't see where I'm going wrong as the code is so simple. I think it has to be the dependencies or something to do with an error in how eve is connecting, though I'm not sure.

Eve seems to be constantly connecting and disconnecting from the database while it is running. I'm not sure if this is a regular thing or not. Anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you connect to the database with the mongo shell?

Comment: Yes I can connect, insert and query from the shell without trouble